How to Recreate Plots with Specific Sample Coordinates in a Seurat Object for GSE137710 Melanoma Data
I'm new to bioinformatics and am trying to reproduce some plots using Seurat in R to check if my analyses (without exact coordinate data) are close to a reference dataset. I'm working with data from the GSE137710 study and am specifically interested in recreating the plots for only the melanoma samples: GSM4085513, GSM4085514, and GSM4085515.
I downloaded the files:
GSE137710_human_melanoma_cell_metadata_9315x14.tsv.gz
GSE137710_human_melanoma_counts_normalized_9315x19445.tsv.gz
However, I'm running into issues with the Cell_ID format not matching or missing coordinates when trying to integrate these into a Seurat object.
I need to store the cell coordinates in the Seurat object for the melanoma samples mentioned, and plot the data based on these coordinates.
How can I align the Cell_ID from the metadata with the normalized counts in a Seurat object?
What’s the best way to add these coordinates to the Seurat object and visualize them?
Any code snippets or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
